# Multi-level ListView derived from XML file?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I'm new to Java and Android. As my first project, I wanted to follow [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) and then modify it. I want change the ListView from a simple playlist to a multi-level "music library". I've written a Python program that scans the MP3's on my PC and spits out an XML file that looks kinda like this:

```
<group name="Epic Music">
    <song file="Globus - Preliator.mp3" />
    <song file="Dimmu Borgir - Gateways.mp3" />
</group>

<group name="Symphonic Metal">
    <song file="Dimmu Borgir - Gateways.mp3" />
    <song file="Nightwish - Wish I Had An Angel.mp3" />
    <song file="Within Temptation - Mother Earth.mp3" />
</group>

<group name="Cultures">

    <group name="Celtic">
        <song file="Loreena McKennitt - The Mummers' Dance.mp3" />
        <song file="Within Temptation - Mother Earth.mp3" />
    </group>

    <group name="French">
        <song file="Celine Dion - Les cloches du hameau.mp3" />
        <song file="Enigma - Sadeness, Pt. 1.mp3" />
    </group>

</group>
```

I want the ListView to be populated by such an XML file, where "group" tags act like folders and subfolders. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: I think you mean `ExpandableListView`. Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

Comment: I don't really want an ExpandableListView. I want something like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/), but the levels shouldn't be hard-coded. They need to be flexible, as derived from an XML file like the one above. But thank for you for the response. Now I know something new.